# Iterative calculations - vectorisation

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to find a way how to implement a fairly simple thing in R. I have a table of inputs that can be grouped by several variables. Basically, what I want is to calculate a column based on this equation

> y[n+1] = ( 1 + a[n] ) * y[n] + b[n]

Columns `a` and `b` are known, so is the initial `y[1]`. I tried to do something like this

```
table %>% mutate(y = cumsum(y + lag(y*a + b,default = 0)))
```

(y, a, b are columns in table) but it didn't work - main issue is that multiplication between y and a columns. I tried to make it work with `reduce` function but because I need two columns (a, b) as parameters for the calculation, it didn't work. I would like to include this code in a pipe. Otherwise I will set up a for loop that should make it work but I thought there must be a way how to do something like this in a nice, vectorised way.

Thanks.

Comment: That equation doesn't imply the use of `cumsum` and I would have tried lag(y)*lag(a), rather than trying to include an product expression inside a lag function. I'm not a dplyr guru so don't know if setting y[1] and then attempting y <- 2* lag(y) would work. Why not try something simple and then proceed from small successes? Also the deleted answer that you saw told you that a) you needed to add data for testing and b) that `cumsum` was not needed, so we should probably be closing the quesation because you failed to [edit] it to bring it up to SO requirements.

Comment: This is an important question.  I took the liberty of adding some sample testing data so it will not be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

> y[n+1] = ( 1 + a[n] ) * y[n] + b[n]

```
table %>% 
  mutate(y = (1 + lag(a)) * lag(y) + lag(b))
```

or more explicitly just to be extra sure of order of operations

```
table %>% 
  mutate(y = ((1 + lag(a)) * lag(y)) + lag(b))
```

Notice that the first value will be NA because (1 + NA) * NA + NA = NA

You shouldn't have any problem with using y[n] to overwrite y[n+1], but just in case you have y problems you could do:

```
table %>% 
  mutate(y1 = (1 + lag(a)) * lag(y) + lag(b))
```

---

**Update**

It has been brought to my attention that I may have misunderstood the available input information. If only the first value of y is available then a different method is needed. It is not possible to use lag because we don't have a prepopulated vector (where all the initial y values are available). Then we are left with just doing a "fast" loop.

```
# If you only have y[1] and no other Y then you can't really do this as a
# vector operation because there is no complete initial vector. 
# Use a fast loop by declaring memory one time only before the loop
table$y <- NA_real_ # initialize all the memory for y column at one time
table$y[1] <- init_y_val # set the initial value of y
for(idx in 2:nrow(table)){
  table$y[idx] <- ((1 + a[idx - 1]) * y[idx -1]) + b[idx -1]
}
```

Comment: Did you try this?  It doesn't seem to run.  It errors out because y has not been defined

Comment: Um, I don't have any sample data to run this code on... you have to have a df table that has a y value (which the author implied they have in their question).  The question didn't include a sample dataset so this is just a method.

Comment: If the user only has the first value of y then they would need to do this differently.